# Problems attaching a file to a task via API with Active Collab v5

Tags: api, activecollab

We are using the API of Active Collab v5, which works quite good.

Unfortunately, we are not able to attach a successfully uploaded file to an existing task. We tried several different ways, but never suceeded.

The one way we believe should work, is shown here:

```
PUT https://<DOMAIN>/api/v1/projects/<PROJECTID>/tasks/<TASKID>
Accept: */*
X-Angie-AuthApiToken: <TOKEN>
Content-Type: text/plain
Accept-Language: en-us
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate

{
  "attach_uploaded_files": [
"<CODE>"
 ]
}

Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
X-Angie-ApplicationVersion: 5.11.23
Pragma: no-cache
Server: Apache
Content-Encoding: gzip
Vary: Accept-Encoding

{"single":{"id":<TASKID>,"class":"Task","url_path":"\/projects\/<PROJECTID>\/ tasks\/
<TASKID>","name":"<TASKNAME>","assignee_id":0,"delegated_by_id":0,
" completed_on":null,"completed_by_id":null,"is_completed":false,"comments_count": 0,
"attachments":[],"labels":[],"is_trashed":false,"trashed_on":null," trashed_by_id":0,
"project_id":<PROJECTID>,"is_hidden_from_clients":false,"body":"<BODYTEXT >",
"body_formatted":"<BODYTEXT>","created_on":1481044542,"created_by_id":20,
" updated_on":1481052449,"updated_by_id":20,"task_number":258,"task_list_id":<TLID> ,
"position":17,"is_important":false,"start_on":null,"due_on":null,"estimate":0,
" job_type_id":0,"total_subtasks":0,"completed_subtasks":0,"open_subtasks":0,
" created_from_recurring_task_id":0},"subscribers":[20],"comments":[],"reminders": [],
"subtasks":[],"task_list":{"id":<TLID>,"class":"TaskList",
"url_path":"\/ projects\/<PROJECTID>\/task-lists\/<TLID>","name":"Inbox",
"is_trashed":false,"trashed_on": null,"trashed_by_id":0,"completed_on":null,
"completed_by_id":null,"is_completed" :false,"project_id":8,"created_on":1480605343,
"created_by_id":20,"updated_on": 1481052420,"updated_by_id":20,"start_on":null,
"due_on":null,"position":1," open_tasks":1,"completed_tasks":44},"tracked_time":0,
"tracked_expenses":0}
```

We always get a 200 OK, but the file remains unattached.

Can someone please tell us what we are doing wrong?

Thank you for your support and best regards.

Lukas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything looks fine except the "Content-Type" header of your request.

Since you are sending a JSON encoded body to the API you need to set the request header to
"**Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8**".

cheers
Nick